# how to get and change xml schema by using php?

Tags: php, xml, database, xsd, dtd

i  only  want  to  know  how  to  get  and  change  data  from  (xml  schema)  by  using (php)  ,  and  check  if
the  data  such  as  ID  is  already  in  the  database ?!

Comment: Give your xml example.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp) is the simple example how to work with xml using php.